# Set value dynamic action not working in apex

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have a problem creating sql dynamic action in oracle apex v4.2. I have two fields, Department number and department name. Department number is a text field with autocomplete. The department name is a display field. On changing the department number, the department name should be displayed by an sql query.

I created a set value dynamic action on department number, giving the correct values in page item to submit and the correct sql query referencing P3_DEPARTMENT_NO.

When i run the page, after select a department number, the department name is not coming up automatically.

Could you please suggest on what i might be missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What event triggers your dynamic action?

Comment: its On Change event. I tried to change the logic to create a button on the page, and on clicking to invoke the dynamic action. but if i need to set values for more than two fields, it just sets value for the first field, and leaves the other fields blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this way:

- First step: In the Shared Components -> Application Processes: create a process myProcess an put your sql dynamic in.
- Second step: Create a javascript function myFunction to call the process myProcess.
- Third step: Use onChange event to call your javascript function myFunction.

Also you can find a lot of exemples on Denes Kubicek app: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=31517:101:116042570427567.

Best regards,

iulian

Answer (score 0):

The exact behaviour of autocomplete lists is probably browser dependent, but generally speaking, don't rely on the "Change" event, as it won't necessarily fire when you select from the list.

You'll need to experiment to get the behaviour you want in your particular situation, but as a starting point you might want to try replacing the "Change" event type on your dynamic action with "Lose focus". That way the dynamic action should always be triggered when you tab or click away from P3_DEPARTMENT_NO.

In similar situations in the past, I've used "Key release" instead of "Lose focus", and I've created a second dynamic action which does the same thing, but triggered by "Get focus". That combination ensures that the display field stays synchronised with the user's selection, whether a value is keyed in or selected from the autocomplete list. Whether or not you go this route depends on how happy you are about the database being hit with your department name query every time a user interacts with P3_DEPARTMENT_NO in any way.

Comment: ok. thank you. is there any limit to the number of values we can set using this dynamic action? i tried creating a button and then on submit, it triggers a dynamic action, which is working in displaying the department name for the department number. But if there are more than around 5 fields which need to be set using two different queries. I added two set of actions within the dynamic action. But all the values are not  being set. the last 2 fields are coming up blank. Could it be that the set value works for only a limited number of field values

Comment: Possibly there is a limit, but you certainly haven't reached it. Out of curiosity I just tested setting 10 field values in one dynamic action and that worked ok. In reality if I had that many fields to look up I might well consider a report instead. Perhaps you should open this as another question, and give more detail on your problem.